# Get the index of the selected item of a datagridview combobox

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I've searched a lot about the way of getting inedx of selected item of combobox inside datagridview but i have not found it !!

I can get the value of selected item by :

```
dataGridView1[j,i]->FormattedValue
```

But i can't get the index !

i've tried to cast DataGridView to DataGridViewComboBoxCell to use (SelectedIndex) property

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell ^ t =  dynamic_cast<DataGridViewComboBoxCell ^>(dataGridView1[j,i])
```

but there isn't any propery shown for "t" !

Comment: Why not iterate over the collection?

Comment: Collection of what ?
if u mean collection of comboboxes.. I want to added it next to some text boxes in shap of array

Comment: please explain you problem more and provide more sample code of what you trying to do.

Comment: there's a combobox inside datagridview and inside this combobox there're set of items.. so i want to get the index of one of those items when it's selected

Comment: Cast the DataGridCell to a DataGridComboBox.  And then just use its SelectedIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not track the selected index.

You could play with its editing control, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, to get the inner ComboBox, but it will be clumsy.

The simplest thing you can do is to lookup via **IndexOf** the cell Value in the collection of all possible values you use to initialize the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Comment: i've tried this casting to DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl and the property "SelectedIndex" appeared but when i run it i get this error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Probably the editing control is generated only when first needed, i.e. when the user tries to change the cell value. So you'd better try to go the index-of way if possible.